# Identify snails

Tags: species-identification, snail

Can you tell me what are these 2 kinds of snails I found?

The first is around 2cm shell diameter. The second is around 3cm shell diameter.

I found both of them in Normandy (north of France) 100km from the sea, and found 2 days ago (summer).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've just edited the post

Answer (score 2):

The first one is Cepaea nemoralis, the [Grove snail](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grove_snail), one of the most common snails.